# Как обратиться к нулевому значению переменной если она объект 'dict_values'

Tags: python, словари, переменные

Код:

```
speed_of_starships = {'CR90 corvette': '950', 'Star Destroyer': '975', 'Sentinel-class landing craft': '1000', 'Death Star': 'n/a'}

for i in speed_of_starships.values(), speed_of_starships:
    if i[0] == 'n/a':
        del speed_of_starships[i][1]
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable
```

Как мне тогда к ней обратиться? Я недавно задавал вопрос как обращаться к нулевому и первому значению. Мне за этот вопрос поставили минус. Я думал что я делал неправильно и из-за этого спросил, но я сделал всё правильно. Он не пытается обращаться в нулевому значению переменной, а пытается обратиться к нулевому элементу нулевого элемента. Ну как минимум я так понимаю.

Comment: Просто то, что возвращает словарь из `.values()` не умеет возвращать значения по индексу, но вы можете привести его в список `list(speed_of_starships.values())`. А вообще, что в коде происходит? `for i in speed_of_starships.values(), speed_of_starships:` - вы знаете что в справа от `in` у вас будет кортеж на 2 элемент, в одном будет `.values`, во втором сам словарь, т.е. у вас цикл будет на 2 итерации: в 1-й получите `speed_of_starships.values()`, а во второй `speed_of_starships`

Answer (score 0):

Просто то, что возвращает словарь из `.values()` не умеет возвращать значения по индексу.

Если хотите пройтись по словарю, сравнивания значения и удалить в нем же, то

- Используйте `.items()` - оно будет возвращать кортежи из пар ключ и значение
- Сравнивая значение, удаляйте по ключу
- Оберните `.items()` в список, чтобы получить копию этого объекта, иначе будет ошибка: `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`, т.к. менять словарь при его итерации запрещено

Пример:

```
speed_of_starships = {'CR90 corvette': '950', 'Star Destroyer': '975', 'Sentinel-class landing craft': '1000', 'Death Star': 'n/a'}

for k, v in list(speed_of_starships.items()):
    if v == 'n/a':
        del speed_of_starships[k]

print(speed_of_starships)
# {'CR90 corvette': '950', 'Star Destroyer': '975', 'Sentinel-class landing craft': '1000'}
```

По аналогии можно перебирать сам словарь, но это будет возвращать его ключи:

```
for k in list(speed_of_starships):
    if speed_of_starships[k] == 'n/a':
        del speed_of_starships[k]
```

Тоже самое:

```
for k in list(speed_of_starships.keys()):
    ...
```

---

Еще вариант - это сгенерировать новый словарь, в которые не включаем те элементы, что не нужны:

```
new_speed_of_starships = {
    k: v
    for k, v in speed_of_starships.items()
    if v != 'n/a'
}
print(new_speed_of_starships)
```